# mayavi number of colors and custom colorscale

Tags: colors, mayavi

I have a matrix out[mXnXp], that have coordinates from a grid

```
xc2,yc2,zc2=np.meshgrid(...)
zs=np.unique(zc2.ravel())
```

I want to plot each "layer" individual, so in the editor I can show/hide individual layers (say Want to see only out[:,:,3] and out[:,:,4]...)

I plot with the following

```
myfig = mlab.figure(1, fgcolor=(1, 1, 1), bgcolor=(0, 0, 0))
for k in range(0,10):
    xx, yy, zz = np.where(zc2==zs[k])
    pp=mlab.points3d(xc2[xx,yy,zz], yc2[xx,yy,zz],  
         zc2[xx,yy,zz],out[xx,yy,zz],
         mode="cube",
         scale_factor=100,scale_mode='none',vmin=0,vmax=8)
```

Now, I want to define a custom colorscale, which has only 10 discrete colors. So I have a matrix

```
imod =[R,G,B,A] of size [10,4]
pp.module_manager.scalar_lut_manager.lut.table=imod
```

But this doesn't work. I believe myavi expects tham imod is of size[256,4]

How can I limit the number of colors in the colorscale and define the ones I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some trial and error I found the follwing command
pp.module_manager.scalar_lut_manager.lut.number_of_colors=10

It works now.